# Using Bootstrap Theme and Aligning Form in Center of Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I would like to center my form in the center of my page (like on the Google homepage) but am having problems doing so. I am using the Bootswatch theme Darkly (hosted from a CDN).

In app.component.html I have:

```
<div>

      <div class="containercenter">
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>

</div>
```

then in app.component.css:

```
#containercenter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;

}
```

I have tried a variety of things in the css file including padding, height, width, align-content,... but none of these seem to work. I have also tried fiddling with the HTML/Bootstrap id or class, different divs. But nothing has worked.

How can I create a Google like layout for my webpage??

For more information see: https://github.com/gf1721/directoryapp

Comment: Modern web development is ridiculously hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `#containercenter` to `.containercenter` and change the css to the following.

```
        .containercenter {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Currently, your code is doing nothing as you've defined a class of containercenter but you've specified in your css to look for an `id` with containercenter. In CSS we use `.classname` for classes and `#idname` for ids.

When you're working with id's your HTML would be

```
<div id="containercenter">
```

Hopefully, this makes sense, I'm happy to elaborate further if you need.

Comment: This has centered it horizontally but not vertically

Comment: I tried  margin-bottom: 0 auto;
  margin-top:0 auto; but this didnt help

Comment: `padding-top: 100px;` for example, will do what you need.

Comment: And looking at it, Google actually does this too :)

Comment: Is there a way to get round using px? Its nice to keep things more flexible

Comment: Thanks for this, each individual technology seems straightforward but combing them together is a nightmare

Comment: Yeah, you could use anything, a percentage if you wanted. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a container with 100% height of the viewport, check if your html and body tags has at least 100% height, then use the Bootstrap 4 flex classes to easily centralize horizontally and vertically.

app.component.css:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.containercenter{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Remove that parent div and do like this

app.component.html

```
<div class="containercenter d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Bootstrap Flexbox helpers:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

If you want to understand how css Flexbox works here a good guide:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/